# Determine iPad version from useragent

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

From our Cordova application that we deploy to iPads we capture the useragent string that typically looks like

Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/13D15 (383223664)

This seems to reveal the iOS version nicely, i.e. 9_2_1, but is there a way to intuit the version of iPad? iPad mini / Air / Air 2 / 4th Gen etc? I know there is a Cordova plugin that exposes a 'device' object in javascript. That will be my next route. But I was hoping I might be able to parse my existing data to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all device information using `ionic.Platform.device()`.
I got device information like this

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  $scope.deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();
});
```

thease information contaion $scope.deviceInformation.

[image]

Hope that will help.

Comment: Ionic is a front end framework with no native component. It cannot do any more than what Cordova can do with regards to the physical device. If information about the physical device is not available through Cordova, ionic cannot add it.